# Which entrypoint does the --entrypoint cli option in the docker compose command override?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So imagine this command:

```bash
docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml run \
  --rm --entrypoint "" \
  my-service
```

and something like this for docker/docker-compose.yml:

```yml
version: '3.9'
services:
  my-service:
    depends_on: other-service
     ...
  other-service:
     ...
```

When I run the command both services come up. But it seems, that both have their entrypoint overridden with "". Is that possible? And if so, how can i archive that only my-services entrypoint gets overridden?

The [docs only state](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/):

```
--entrypoint            Override the entrypoint of the image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker compose run` only starts a single service from the docker-compose.yml file.

`docker compose run my-service` starts the service `my-service`. So the `--entrypoint` argument only affects the specified service.

Comment: It starts the seconds service as well because of the depends_on entry.

Comment: ```docker compose run``` should start all services defined in ```docker-compose.yaml```. Your statement in the post is a bit misleading.